# Using the data from a drop down calendar in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I'm using LibreOffice to make a spreadsheet (in Calc, obviously) and have inserted a Date Field Form Control.  I edited it the way I want so it has a drop down calendar.

However, when I go to the form control, there's no "Data" tab.  Normally, if you have another type of form input - a checkbox, for example - there is a "General", "Events", and "Data" tab.  You can link the data to a specific cell to see if the checkbox is "TRUE" or "FALSE".

There's no data tab!  I can not for the life of me figure out how to USE the date that gets entered into the date field!  You can simply select and have the date displayed in a floating field on a spreadsheet. . .  I feel like this should be super obvious but I've looked through Oo and Google for quite a while now.

**TL;DR:  Does anyone know how to *use* the data from a date form field?**

Comment: In case, you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask at 1: http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Users-f1639498.html or 2: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/ or 3: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/ *Also, please mention your LibreOffice version number!*

Comment: Problem is present in LibreOffice Version 3.6.2.2 (Build ID: 360m1(Build:2)).

Comment: Could also be reported as a bug: https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/bug/